# Javascript counter not working when using JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, json

have a json file named `json.json`. It has the same data as `var json` below but for some reason is not working when pulling from the url which is saved in the same directory.

```
<script>
//var json = '{"Id": "0001","Type": "Type","Theme": "Default","Auto": "True","Countdown": 600,"Timer": 480000,"Max": 5,"List":{ "Names":[{"Name":"Name 9", "Account": "1009", "IsWinner":"False"},{"Name":"Name 10", "Account": "1010", "IsWinner":"False"},{"Name":"Name 11", "Account": "1011", "IsWinner":"False"},{"Name":"Name 12", "Account": "1012", "IsWinner":"False"},{"Name":"Name 13", "Account": "1013", "IsWinner":"False"},{"Name":"Name 14", "Account": "1014", "IsWinner":"False"},{"Name":"Name 15", "Account": "1015", "IsWinner":"False"}]}}',

    var json = 'json.json'
    obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);

var seconds = obj.Countdown;
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('feed').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        document.getElementById('feed').innerHTML = "00:00";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: `var = 'json.json' //local file not working` HUH?

Comment: The line does not make sense.

Comment: @epascarello. sorry, isee it now. that was a type. it's actually var json = 'json.json',

Comment: What is your question? Also, what is your error?

Comment: `var json = 'json.json'` simply assigns the string `'json.json'` to the `json` variable. It doesn't open the file or read any data from the file. So, you are trying to parse that string as if it were json, which it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a XHR to get your JSON file ... Jquery will help you make a cross browser ajax request

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nuhigo/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Very basically:

```
$.get(url, function(JSON){dowhatyouwantwith(JSON)});
```

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: i see my mistake, thanks. still not workin, though. when i uplaod to my site it's blank. i even used ur code and URL js file and all blank... it might be hosting??

Comment: i've decided to use jQuery for this. thakn you for ur help/